# Integrate matplotlib plot in pyqt5 from qt generated code

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5, figure

How will I integrate matplot lib with pyqt5? I have tried a lot to integrate but not able to do it. Basically, I want to display my plot when I click a button in the **same main window**.

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.plot)
```

below is the entire code,piece of the code generated from QT designer.

Using this code I should be able to jump to plot function

```
 def plot(self):
        plt.magnitude_spectrum(self.y_time, self.sr)
        plt.show()
```

and get a plot of the spectrum .

Sample code generated from Qt designer using pyqt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def plot():
        plt.magnitude_spectrum(rate and data)
        plt.show()


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 190, 85, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 85, 27))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 27))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "display plot "))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "load audio "))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is very chaotic. There are several placed where you define a figure and the `plot` function appears twice in the code. Can you make sure to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have edited again. Is the information enough?

Comment: Not sure. In the new code you never call that function?

Comment: self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.plot) calls it

Comment: In the code you forgot to define the arguments to `magnitude_spectrum`. Also, `def plot(self, evt):` needs two arguments. And finally, it may make sense not to call `plt.show()`, because the event loop is already started at that point. Hence better use `plt.gcf().show()`.